# How to store symmetric secret key in Java PKCS12 keystore

Tags: cryptography, keystore, pkcs#12

I need a secure store for symmetric keys that works for both .NET and Java. I need to be able to store and retrieve HmacSha* keys from the same store in both languages, programmatically, not via command line tools.

My first attempt at this was generating and storing a key from Java using the PKCS12 keystore, which is a portable format, and one which I would have thought supports storing secret keys as well as private keys for X.509 certs.

My experience so far, though, is that it does not (NOTE: Java SE 6), throwing an exception on calls to java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(), complaining that the key I'm trying to store is not a PrivateKey.

I found one article claiming that this should be possible: http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1420427307-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----PKCS12

But, if I pull the example code from that article (the example under the section titled "Store secret key"), I get the same exception on the same call to setKeyEntry().

Does anyone know whether what I can meet these requirements using the PKCS12 keystore in Java?

FWIW, here's the code:

```
public void gen( String thePath, String thePassword ) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    Key key = keygen.generateKey();

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keystore.load(null, null);

    // This call throws an exception
    keystore.setKeyEntry("theKey", key, thePassword.toCharArray(), null);
    keystore.store( new FileOutputStream(thePath), thePassword.toCharArray() );
}
```

**EDIT:** Hmmm - looking into this on the .NET side reveals that there is also no direct programmatic support for importing/exporting symmetric keys using the PKCS12 format. It seems like the best supported approach would be to have an X.509 key pair that is used to encrypt the symmetric key, and to store/transport that pair in a PKCS12 file, together with the encrypted symmetric key, to any other system that needs to use the symmetric key.

Anyone encountered this same problem found a workable solution?

Comment: Using the asymmetric solution seems acceptable to me. It's not as efficient but probably efficient enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `KeyStore` implementations of Java SE have gained a lot of attention in the later releases. Your code should run fine on Java SE 8 for JCEKS key stores, but not on Java SE 7.

You probably need to wait for Java 9 for PKCS#12 support. Java 9 will focus on support for PKCS#12 key stores.

Comment: Drat - Java 8's probably not an option for me, and even if it were, it looks like I'd run into problems using .NET API's to extract symmetric keys from the PKCS12 format - those libraries assume the only thing you'd want to store in a PKCS12 file is X.509 objects.

Comment: Java 7 is near end of life. If Java 8 is not an option for you, what is? Yeah, .NET and Java are pretty much geared towards X509. Better go with the flow...

Comment: Marking this as the solution because it's correct about Java SE 7 support for SecretKey storage in the PKCS keystore. But really, there doesn't appear to be a solution for exchanging symmetric keys between Java and .NET using PKCS12.

Comment: Haven't seen anything like a PKCS#12 store for symmetric keys in .NET but I'm not as proficient in .NET as in Java. Pretty sure I should have seen it by now though if it exists.